# Can only RDP to PC from Mac

Tags: networking, windows-10, remote-desktop

I previously setup remote desktop on a Windows 10 Home computer a couple years ago, but I can't remember how I did it.

I can currently remote into the system from a Mac (local network via IP) with a password that IS NOT the password to the PC.  However, I can't connect from a different PC (also running Windows 10 Home).

I am on the same network with all 3 computers.  When I try and connect from a PC I get an error that it can't connect because of one of these options:

1. Remote Access to the server is not enabled (it clearly is if I am able to connect from Mac screensharing)
2. The remote computer is turned off (also not true)
3. The remote computer is not available on the network

Can anyone assist? My main goal is to connect from a PC and also change the remote password that I am using from Mac.

Comment: The bottom line is that you [cannot RDP into a Windows 10 Home operating system](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10/windows-10-home-verson-remote-desktop-capability/9551bfa6-c365-4101-954c-7d561dd64087).  You would need to either upgrade the system to Windows 10 Pro, or utilize third-party remote access application.

Comment: @Run5k I’m sure this can be an answer...

Comment: Perhaps so.  I am awaiting feedback from the OP first, in case it was simply a misunderstanding regarding the OS capabilities.

Comment: Does screenshare from macOS use a different protocol than RDP?

Comment: That's quite possible, but I am the furthest thing from a macOS guru.  However, I do know a bit more about Windows than the average bear.  The bottom line is that you cannot RDP into a Windows 10 Home machine from another Windows computer.  You would need to use something like TeamViewer or a flavor of VNC for remote access into that machine.

Comment: Okay, I had read that, but was confused since I can connect from macOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows 10 Home operating system can utilize the **Remote Desktop Connection** client to access other Windows machines such as a server OS or a Windows 10 Pro workstation.

On the other hand, you [cannot actually RDP into a Windows 10 Home operating system from another Windows machine](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10/windows-10-home-verson-remote-desktop-capability/9551bfa6-c365-4101-954c-7d561dd64087).  You would need to use a third-party remote access application such as TeamViewer or VNC to do that.

Comment: Accepted.  I was thrown off by my ability to access screensharing from macOS, but it seems like that isn't the same protocol.